# How to remove all CRLF in file (not replace with LF)

Tags: files, text-processing, sed, newlines

I'd like to remove all carriage returns followed by line feeds (CRLF), such as `\r\n` in a file. How can I do that? I can't use `dos2unix` because that replaces CRLF with LF. And I can't use `tr` because that will also replace any `\n` that aren't preceded by `\r`. How can I do this?

Comment: I tried `sed -i 's/\r\n//g' file` which didn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sed ":a;/\r$/{N;s/\r\n//;b a}"
```

This will match all lines that have `'\r'` at the end (followed by `'\n'`). On these lines it will first append the next line of input (while putting the `'\n` separator in between), then replace the resulting `"\r\n"` with an empty string, and then goes back to the beginning to see, whether the new contents of pattern space doesn't by chance happen to match again.

Following the comment: if you wanted to strip any additional `'\r'` from the file as well, just add it after stripping the CRLF combos:

```
sed ":a;/\r$/{$!N;s/\r\n//;t a};s/\r//g"
```

Comment: Cool! Btw is there a way to modify that command to strip all occurrences of `\r` in addition to `\r\n` from the file? (Rather than having to run a second command to get rid of `\r` using something like `tr`.)

Comment: Thanks peterph, it works great. (And mikeserv for an edit.) Putting 2 sed commands in the same command separated by a semicolon is more efficient than running them as 2 separate commands? Meaning it only has to scan the file through once and just runs both commands on each line?

Comment: Yes. Plus you save a couple of miliseconds on creating a new process.

Comment: @mikeserv thanks for the edit. However the branch command needs modifying as well - the unconditional one I had there was causing an endless loop on the last line.

Comment: Maybe like `sed -e :n -e '/^M$/{$s///p;N' -e '};s/.\n//;tn'` The problem is though that `sed` isnt designed for unlimited line length. If youre relying on gnu extensions `-z` is probably easiest: `sed -z 's/\r\n//g'`. But then youre working with long pattern spaces. At lest that way though you can clear it without printing a newline - so once per edit. And `sed` probably doesnt save much here - im willing to bet an additional `tr` would actually save processing time.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to reach for `perl` one-liners when doing anything that involves manipulating line endings:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN {undef $/} s/\r\n//g' *.txt
```

The key to making this work is the `undef $/`, which makes Perl read each file as one string, which you can then do a search-and-replace on.  To strip bare `\r` as well, just tweak the regex:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN {undef $/} s/\r\n?//g' *.txt
```

Comment: `perl -pe 'BEGIN {undef $/} s/\r(?=\n)//g' *.txt`

Comment: @AvinashRaj That is the same as `dos2unix`, which is specifically not what the OP wanted.